# uploading large files with monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm using a webclient to upload a *relatively* large file (40mb) via the **UploadFileAsync** method.

As I'm testing this on an emulator, the connection speed is quite fast. I can see the **UploadProgressChanged** is getting called frequently, and reaches 100% within around 20 secs.

However, the **UploadFileCompleted** doesn't get called for another **12 minutes!!**

If I upload a smaller file (say, 500kb), **UploadFileCompleted** gets called almost as soon as the upload progress reaches 100%.

I'm wondering if this has something to do with threads? I can't imagine how, though.

In terms of the web server, it officially receives the file when **UploadFileCompleted** gets called, and not a minute before. So my other thought is that the **UploadProgressChanged** is just wrong.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should have looked a bit deeper before posting.

I thought it was odd that the upload happened so quickly. What's happening is the app is saying 'upload this!' and android is saying 'ok!'.. and it *thinks* it's been uploaded. but it just sits in a queue with android.

there is a fix here:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3100

Basically, inherit from WebClient and override getwebrequest, and set **AllowWriteStreamBuffering** to false. Here's my simple code:

```
public class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    long contentLength;

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var req = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
        req.ContentLength = contentLength;
        return req;
    }

    public MyWebClient(long contentLength)
    {
        this.contentLength = contentLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: This fix works for other platforms as well (e.g. Mono on Linux).